# SignalR Communicating Between Hubs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub

How would I communicate between two separate hubs?

So Hub1 is my ChatHub for Support Agents and Hub2 is my Hub for customers.
Support agents have logins, customers have a form they fill out which creates a user and so on. But how can I pass the user created from Hub2 to Hub1 for all the users who have a Hub1(Support Agents) or is there some better way to do this?

Would I need to handle it all in Hub1 with some logic for differentiating between customers and agents?

May not be possible since the Hubs aren't static they are created per user right?

The problem with doing it all in one Hub is after the form is filled out it sends them to another page so they get a new connectionId and they have no Context.User.Identity.Name so there is no way to grab them again since I don't know their information from the new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GlobalHost.ConnectionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.globalhost.connectionmanager%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for communicating between Hubs:

```
var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubName>();
ctx.Clients.All.methodName(parameter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll look into this later this weekend

Comment: Just now had a chance to really read this. So I can grab Hub B from Hub A that way and then call it's methods just like from javascript(client side) ?

Comment: @Nathan Yes,  Now you have a reference to the hub.

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what I'm looking for. I need to call server code not client code. So I need access to the Hub1 methods from Hub2

Comment: Creating an instance of Hub1 in Hub2 may serve my purpose, certainly allows me to add the customer to the static dictionary.

Comment: Actually, the easiest way may be just to use one hub and add customers as limited users and remove them after each session. Thanks for your help tough!

Comment: Is there a way to communicate ebtween two signalr CORE servers?